# Pytest fails on distinct with sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I've a django system with drf where my views work fine, however, I'm unable to write a test for a view which has the following query:

```
Object.objects.filter(...).order_by(...).distinct('comdate')
```

. The problem is the distinct and it fails with the following error:

```
#python -m pytest -k celler --pdb
self = <django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations.DatabaseOperations object at 0x7f9dd7418a90>, fields = ['"tis_tislog"."comdate"'], params = [[]]

def distinct_sql(self, fields, params):
    """
    Return an SQL DISTINCT clause which removes duplicate rows from the
    result set. If any fields are given, only check the given fields for
    duplicates.
    """
    if fields:
>           raise NotSupportedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
E           django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py:176: 
NotSupportedError


entering PDB 


PDB post_mortem (IO-capturing turned off) > 
/home/user/prj5/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py(176)distinct_sql()
-> raise NotSupportedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
(Pdb) c

PDB continue (IO-capturing resumed)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[100%]


short test summary info 
FAILED 

prj5/tests/test_tis_view.py::TestTisUpdateView::
test_responds_ok_for_authorized_clients - django.db.utils.NotSupportedError:
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

.

The test itself is pretty simple:

```
class SomeTestingView:
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def testTisView(self, client: Client):
        client.get(URL)
```

Is there any way how I could make this test running?

Comment: `.distinct(fieldname)` only works for PostgreSQL, SQLite can only use `.distinct()` *without* fields.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem: is there any workaround for it in the tests?

Comment: no, unless you somehow would "mock" it, but then likely the result of the test would depend more on how good the mocking is, and if you later change the view, then likely it will require even more work to fix the mocking properly.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem: So it would be easier to rewrite the query in the view? However, I don't know if has a good similar query. What I can think now only to involve some python which makes it not that elegant and slow.

Comment: run your tests on Postgres so they are similar to how your application actually runs

Comment: Jimmy Pells: Can You give me some hint how to do that?